# Swift 3 - full width of UITabBarItem for selectionIndicatorImage

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

i have a UITabBar with three tabs. Now I want to assign or lets say to fill the complete width of one tab to the related selectionIndicatorImage cause currently I got a border if a tab is selected. Like the tab on the left side shows in the following screenshot:

[image: border]

I made a subclass of UITabBar with a new property:

```
var activeItemBackground:UIColor = UIColor.white {
    didSet {

        let numberOfItems = CGFloat((items!.count))

        let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: frame.width / numberOfItems,
                                    height: frame.height)

        selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: activeItemBackground,
                                     size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero)

        frame.size.width = frame.width + 4
        frame.origin.x = -2


    }
}
```

And the UIImage-Extension in order to have backgroundColor and an image:

```
extension UIImage
{
    class func imageWithColor(color: UIColor, size: CGSize) -> UIImage
    {
        let rect: CGRect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
        color.setFill()
        UIRectFill(rect)
        let image: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return image
    }
}
```

I read much stuff about this problem but unfortunately I can't get it to work. Is something missing in my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're taking a couple extra steps...

You are calculating the exact size of the tab bar item, and creating an image of *that size*, so you shouldn't need the `.resizableImage` part.

And, since you are setting to exact size, you also shouldn't need to resize the tab bar frame.

This appears to work fine in my testing (using your `.imageWithColor` func):

```
class MyTabBar: UITabBar {

    var activeItemBackground:UIColor = UIColor.white {
        didSet {

            let numberOfItems = CGFloat((items!.count))

            let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: frame.width / numberOfItems,
                                        height: frame.height)

            selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: activeItemBackground,
                                                             size: tabBarItemSize)

        }
    }

}
```

Then in viewDidLoad of the first VC:

```
    if let tb = self.tabBarController?.tabBar as? MyTabBar {
        tb.activeItemBackground = UIColor.red
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Your code works fine. My fault was also your last code snippet cause I set the activeItemBackground to early in my code.